# Updating XML with namespace with xmlstarlet 1.6.1

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces, wildfly-8, xmlstarlet

I am trying to update the host-slave.xml from a Wildfly Cluster configuration with xmlstarlet.

I am using the following statement:

```
xml ed -N my=urn:jboss:domain:2.2 -u "_:host/management/security-realms/security-realm[@name='UndertowRealm']/server-identities/ssl/keystore/@path" -v "test" Wildfly\wildfly-8.2.0.Final\WildFly-HOST\configuration\host-slave.xml
```

The namespace definition in xml:

```
<host name="172.16.1.11" xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:2.2" >
```

The part of the xml I want to change:

```
<security-realm name="UndertowRealm">  
    <server-identities>  
        <ssl>  
            <keystore path="D:\wildfly-8.2.0.Final\ssl\wildfly.keystore"  keystore-password="rsaddbTsadYvvMXZ" alias="wildfly"  /> 
        </ssl>  
    </server-identities>  
</security-realm>
```

But if I delete the namespace defition from the xml, and use the following statement:

```
xml ed -u ":host/management/security-realms/security-realm[@name='UndertowRealm']/server-identities/ssl/keystore/@path" -v "test" Wildfly\wildfly-8.2.0.Final\WildFly-HOST\configuration\host-slave.xml
```

It works as expected, so it is not an Issue with XPATH. 
As I dont know what happens to wildfly if I delete the namespace declaration, I would like to keep it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you need to use the declared prefix (`my`, which you correctly mapped to the default namespace URI) to reference element in that namespace in your XPath, for example :

```
/my:security-realm[@name='UndertowRealm']/my:server-identities/my:ssl/my:keystore/@path
```

Basically, all element without prefix, within element where default namespace is declared, are considered in the same default namespace, hence need to be referenced using the prefix `my`.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with version 1.2.1 you can use de default namespace `_`
(drop the `-N` argument)

```
xml ed -u "/_:security-realm[@name='UndertowRealm']/_:server-identities/_:ssl/_:keystore/@path" -v "test" Wildfly\wildfly-8.2.0.Final\WildFly-HOST\configuration\host-slave.xml
```

As explained [here](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch05.html):

> 1.3. A More Convenient Solution
>
> XML documents can also use different namespace prefixes, on any
>   element in the document. In order to handle namespaces with greater
>   ease, XMLStarlet (versions 1.2.1+) will use the namespace prefixes
>   declared on the root element of the input document. The default
>   namespace will be bound to the prefixes "_" and "DEFAULT" (in versions
>   1.5.0+).