# xmlstarlet to delete wildfly extension or subsystem or value?

Tags: jboss, wildfly, xmlstarlet

I am trying to use xmlstarlet to delete an extension in wildly configuration file aka standalone.xml , but it does not seem to work.

Here is what I do:

```
 xmlstarlet el -v /tmp/standalone.xml |grep ejb
```

Which returns me the xpath of the extension I want to delete:

```
server/extensions/extension[@module='org.jboss.as.ejb3']
```

Then I try to delete it with "ed -d " , but it remains present:

```
 xmlstarlet  ed -d 'server/extensions/extension[@module="org.jboss.as.ejb3"]'    /tmp/standalone.xml |head
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Any reason you're not using Wildfly's CLI? It could be automated too and would validate your modifications (for instance I tried `/extension=org.jboss.as.ejb3:remove` which failed because I still had the `ejb3` subsystem declared ; modifying the XML directly you'd have to restart the server to be aware of that error)

Comment: I want to do it before server startup, when the server is offline actually.

Comment: Since extentions are one-liners, I'd use this `sed` command : `sed -i.bak '/<extension module="org.jboss.as.ejb3"/d' /path/to/standalone.xml`. Not best practice, but it should do the trick. It'll create a `.bak` backup file and change the file in-place

Comment: it is not only about extension, I will do it for the whole subsystem just after. And of course, I prefer using a single tool and syntax instead of many.

Comment: Yeah, `sed` could do both but I agree `xmlstarlet` would be better. I'll check if I can see what's wrong with your command, but I haven't had great experiences with xmlstarlet so far

Comment: I think I found the issue: xmlstarlet does not really like xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:5.0" , by removing it works. Let's find out the right option to make it work

Comment: I think this is documented [here](http://xmlstar.sourceforge.net/doc/UG/ch05s01.html)

Answer (score 2):

Here is the final solution, which is not hyper intuitive, because it requires to add the namespace prefix for each entity not only at the root level. (We need to repeat the d: prefix at every level of the xpath)

```
xmlstarlet ed -N d="urn:jboss:domain:5.0" -d "d:server/d:extensions/d:extension[@module='org.jboss.as.ejb3']"   standalone/configuration/standalone.xml
```

thanks to Aaron also to point out the documentation which gives a few inputs.

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37407022/updating-xml-with-namespace-with-xmlstarlet-1-6-1